# Use UP/DOWN arrow keys to call a function (and passing parameter)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a survey in which there are numerous text inputs taking numerical value each of which has a pair of increment/decrement buttons. I have a working function as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="text-input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="buttons inc-dec">
        <button class="increment">Increment</button>
        <button class="decrement">Decrement</button>
    </div>
</div>

function incDec(btnClass)   {

    var input       = $(this).closest('.text-input-wrapper').find('input');
    var inputVal    = $(this).closest('.text-input-wrapper').find('input').val();

    if ($(this).hasClass('increment')) {
        if (inputVal.length == 0) {
            ($(input).val('1'));
        }
        else {
            inputVal++;
            $(input).val(inputVal);
        }
    } // increment

    else if ($(this).hasClass('decrement')) {
        if (inputVal.length == 0) {
            ($(input).val('0'));
        }
        else {
            inputVal--;
            $(input).val(inputVal);
        }
    } // decrement

    return false;

} // function incDec
```

Now I need to enable incrementing and decrementing value using the UP & DOWN keys; I took a stab with the following but with no joy:

```
$(document).keydown( function(eventObject) {
    // UP arrow
    if(eventObject.which==38) {
        var btnClass = "increment";
    } else

    // DOWN arrow
    if(eventObject.which==40) {
        var btnClass = "decrement";
    }
    incDec(btnClass);
```

I’d greatly appreciate some clarification as to how to go about firing the increment/decrement using the up/down keys,

Many thanks in advance,

svs

Comment: Thanks gents. I've edited my question, as in fact I did have the incDec function taking the btnClass parameter. Still no joy; I'm especially newb re: passing arguments/parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your `incDec` function is not designed to take the class as an input parameter - it uses the object that calls the event (i.e. the click event on a button).

It's a bit hacky, but how about something like below? You assign the click handler to each button then invoke the relevant button's click-event.

```
$( function ( ) {
    $('button').click( incDec );

    $('input').keydown( function(eventObject) {

        // UP arrow
        if(eventObject.which==38) {
            var btnClass = "increment";
        } else

        // DOWN arrow
        if(eventObject.which==40) {
            var btnClass = "decrement";
        }

        // Invoke the click event for the inc/dec button inside the containing div.
        $('button.'+btnClass, $(this).parent( )).click( );
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle with two such boxes. when you use the up/down arrow keys while inside a text-box it increments/decrements correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/zJBEN/

Comment: Thx Ian, but adding your function to mine, both the arrow keys and the buttons are incrementing/decrementing by 2. I'm still hacking at it but this ain't my area so confidence is medium-low :) Cheers, svs

Comment: Could you show me the code you're using as it worked ok for me in the JSfiddle so I'm wondering if there's something being called twice.

Comment: yeah man there was something being called twice 'cause I spaced out ;) .. removing my click statement resolved it. However I discover yet another issue, though unrelated to my question or your answer: when keying down, FF shows the form history of numbers, not matching where the scrolling input value. Anyway, thanks a ton, I think I can ship it this way. Much appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you need to disable autocomplete on those form elements. Unfortunately, based on an quick Google search, there doesn't seem to be a standards compliant way of doing this, but you might get away with adding `autocomplete="off"` to your input boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).keypress( function(eventObject) {
    var key = (eventObject.keyCode ? eventObject.keyCode : eventObject.which);
    if(key==38) {
        var btnClass = "increment";
    } else
    // DOWN arrow
    if(key==40) {
        var btnClass = "decrement";
    }
    incDec(btnClass);
});
```

Comment: `incDec` isn't set to take the class as a parameter - it uses the class of the event's caller, so I don't think this would work.

Comment: @ianhales - yeah I jsut saw your post - I'm leaving my desk for a few, but I'm going to look more at this when I get back - I'll delete it if it doesn't work

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Thanks Zach, helped me get in the zone, cheers.